# How to change empty strings to NULLS

Tags: ssis

I'm using `SQL Server 2008 Integration Services (SSIS)` and would like change empty strings on one of my columns (Unicode string(DT_WSTR-50)) to `NULLs`. I found some related posts but that doesnt seem to work.

I tried:
`Column == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : Column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([ColumnName])))==0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : LTRIM(RTRIM([ColumnName]))
```